# Intent и фрагмент activity

Tags: java, android

столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как через Intent заставить activity вызвать нужный фрагмент, (по дефолту открывается другой), буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Мало информации в вопросе. Исходя из множества предположений могу лишь предложить использовать `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` метод активити вместе с корректным флагом для активити в манифесте (`launchMode="singleTop"`). Но, возможно, вы вообще не об этом.

Comment: Добавьте в Intent флаг через putExtra() и в onCreate считывайте пришедший intent и достаньте оттуда этот флаг, если флаг передается, открываете фрагмент, который Вам нужен, если нет - открываете фрагмент по дефолту

Answer (score 0):

Какой Intent? Зачем?

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "string");

Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```